# Airflow 1.10.3 SubDag can only run 1 task in parallel even the concurrency is 8

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-scheduler

Recently, I upgrade Airflow from 1.9 to 1.10.3 (latest one).

However I do notice a performance issue related to SubDag concurrency. Only 1 task inside the SubDag can be picked up, which is not the way it should be, our concurrency setting for the SubDag is 8.

See the following:
`get_monthly_summary-214` and `get_monthly_summary-215` are the two SubDags, it can be run in parallel controller by the parent dag concurrency

[image]

But when zoom into the SubDag say `get_monthly_summary-214`, then
[image]
You can definitely see that there is only 1 task running at a time, the others are queued, and it keep running in this way. When we check the SubDag concurrency, it is actually 8 as we specified in the code:
[image]

We do setup the pool slots size, it is 32, We do have 8 celery workers to pick up the queued task, and our airflow config associate with the concurrency is as follows:

```
# The amount of parallelism as a setting to the executor. This defines
# the max number of task instances that should run simultaneously
# on this airflow installation
parallelism = 32

# The number of task instances allowed to run concurrently by the scheduler
dag_concurrency = 16

# The app name that will be used by celery
celery_app_name = airflow.executors.celery_executor

# The concurrency that will be used when starting workers with the
# "airflow worker" command. This defines the number of task instances that
# a worker will take, so size up your workers based on the resources on
# your worker box and the nature of your tasks
worker_concurrency = 16
```

Also all the SubDag are configured using the queue called `mini`, while all its inner tasks are the default queue called `default`, since we might some [deadlock problems](https://medium.com/@team_24989/fixing-subdagoperator-deadlock-in-airflow-6c64312ebb10) before if we running both SubDag operator and SubDag inner tasks on the same queue. I also tried to use the `default` queue for all the tasks and operators, it does not help.

The old version 1.9 seems to be fine that each SubDag can execute multiple tasks in parallel, did we miss anything ?

Answer (score 10):

Based on the Finding of @kaxil posted above, a work around solution if you still would like to execute tasks inside a subdag in parallel is creating a wrapper functiuon to explicitly pass the `executor` when construct `SubDagOperator`:

```
from airflow.operators.subdag_operator import SubDagOperator
from airflow.executors import GetDefaultExecutor

def sub_dag_operator_with_default_executor(subdag, *args, **kwargs):
    return SubDagOperator(subdag=subdag, executor=GetDefaultExecutor(), *args, **kwargs)
```

call `sub_dag_operator_with_default_executor` when you created your subdag operator. In order to relieve the sub dag operator [performance concerns](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/3251)

> We should change the default executor for subdag_operator to SequentialExecutor. Airflow pool is not honored by subdagoperator, hence it could consume all the worker resources(e.g in celeryExecutor). This causes issues mentioned in airflow-74 and limits the subdag_operator usage. We use subdag_operator in production by specifying using sequential executor.

We suggest to create a special queue (we specifiy queue='mini' in our cases) and celery worker to handle the subdag_operator, so that it is not consume all your normal celery worker's resources. As follows:

```
 dag = DAG(
    dag_id=DAG_NAME,
    description=f"{DAG_NAME}-{__version__}",
    ...
)    
with dag:
        ur_operator = sub_dag_operator_with_default_executor(
                task_id=f"your_task_id",
                subdag=load_sub_dag(
                    parent_dag_name=DAG_NAME,
                    child_dag_name=f"your_child_dag_name",
                    args=args,
                    concurrency=dag_config.get("concurrency_in_sub_dag") or DEFAULT_CONCURRENCY,
                ),
                queue="mini",
                dag=dag
            )
```

Then when you create your special celery worker (we are using a light weight host like 2 cores and 3G memory), specify `AIRFLOW__CELERY__DEFAULT_QUEUE` as `mini`, depends on how much sub dag operator you would like to run in parallel, you should create multiple special celery workers to load balances the resources, we suggest, each special celery worker should take care at most 2 sub dag operator at a time, or it will be exhausted (e.g., run out of memory on a 2 core and 3G memory host)

Also you can adjust `concurrency` inside your subdag via the ENV VAR `concurrency_in_sub_dag` created in airflow UI `Variables` configuration page.

Update [22/05/2020] the above only work for airflow (<=1.10.3, >= 1.10.0)
For airflow beyone 1.10.3, please use

```
from airflow.executors import get_default_executor
```

instead.

Comment: Very helpful.  N.B. from 1.10.4 `GetDefaultExecutor` has been renamed `get_default_executor`

Comment: BTW  the ALL_SKIPPED bug has been fixed in 1.10.5 which means _one_ of the reasons to use a `SubDag` has been removed

Comment: Thanks a lot. Including the `get_default_executor` import, using the executor `executor=get_default_executor()` in the function `sub_dag_operator_with_default_executor` and use that function instead of SubDagOperator has solved the issue.

Comment: Should the tasks within the subdag have the same queue as the subdag itself?

Answer (score 7):

That is because in Airflow 1.9.0, the default Executor was used by SubdagOperator.

**Airflow 1.9.0**:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.9.0/airflow/operators/subdag_operator.py#L33

```
class SubDagOperator(BaseOperator):

    template_fields = tuple()
    ui_color = '#555'
    ui_fgcolor = '#fff'

    @provide_session
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(
            self,
            subdag,
            executor=GetDefaultExecutor(),
            *args, **kwargs):
```

However, from Airflow 1.10 and onwards, the default executor for SubDagOperator is changed to SequentialExecutor

**Airflow >=1.10**:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.0/airflow/operators/subdag_operator.py#L38

```
class SubDagOperator(BaseOperator):

    template_fields = tuple()
    ui_color = '#555'
    ui_fgcolor = '#fff'

    @provide_session
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(
            self,
            subdag,
            executor=SequentialExecutor(),
            *args, **kwargs):
```

The commit that changed it is https://github.com/apache/airflow/commit/64d950166773749c0e4aa0d7032b080cadd56a53#diff-45749879e4753a355c5bdb5203584698

And the detailed reason it was changed can be found in https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/3251

> We should change the default executor for subdag_operator to SequentialExecutor. Airflow pool is not honored by subdagoperator, hence it could consume all the worker resources(e.g in celeryExecutor). This causes issues mentioned in airflow-74 and limits the subdag_operator usage. We use subdag_operator in production by specifying using sequential executor.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right, I found the difference here as well https://github.com/apache/airflow/commit/64d950166773749c0e4aa0d7032b080cadd56a53#diff-45749879e4753a355c5bdb5203584698 
It do limit the usage of SubDagOperator, sad.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks!.
I changed a little bit the code for the latest airflow (1.10.5) GetDefaultExecutor not working anymore:

```
from airflow.executors.celery_executor import CeleryExecutor

def sub_dag_operator_with_celery_executor(subdag, *args, **kwargs):
return SubDagOperator(subdag=subdag, executor=CeleryExecutor(), *args, 
**kwargs)
```

Comment: U can still use default executor as 
"from airflow.executors import get_default_executor". if celeryExecutor (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/executor/celery.html) does not fit

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @kaxil and @kevin-li for their answers. They served as the foundation for the below. The simplest way to solve is to skip the wrapper function and call the SubDagOperator directly within the DAG flow (In my opinion it'll improve readability a tad). Please note below should be treated still as pseudo code but should provide guidance as to the pattern needed to scale without consuming all workers with a large scale SubDag:

```
# This below works for Airflow versions above 1.10.3 . See @kevin-li's answer for deets on lower versions
from airflow.executors import get_default_executor
from airflow.models import DAG
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.operators.subdag_operator import SubDagOperator

dag = DAG(
         dag_id="special_dag_with_sub",
         schedule_interval="5 4 * * *",
         start_date=datetime(2021, 6, 1),
         concurrency=concurrency
    )

with dag:
        subdag_queue = "subdag_queue"

        operator_var = SubDagOperator(
                task_id="your_task_id",
                subdag=special_sub_dag(
                    parent_dag_name=dag.dag_id,
                    child_dag_name="your_child_dag_name",
                    queue=subdag_queue,
                    concurrency=DAG_CONCURRENCY_VALUE_OF_YOUR_CHOICE_HERE,
                    args=args,
                ),
                executor=get_default_executor(),
                queue=subdag_queue,
                dag=dag
            )
```

While having the SubDagOperator owned by a specific worker queue is important I would argue it's also important to pass the queue to the tasks within it. That can be done like the following:

```
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

def special_sub_dag(parent_dag_name, child_dag_name, concurrency, queue, *args):
    dag = DAG(
            dag_id=f"{parent_dag_name}.{child_dag_name}",
            schedule_interval="5 4 * * *",
            start_date=datetime(2021, 6, 1),
            concurrency=concurrency,
        )

    do_this = PythonOperator(
            task_id="do_this",
            dag=dag,
            python_callable=lambda: "hello world",
            queue=queue,
        )

    then_this = DummyOperator(
        task_id="then_this",
        dag=dag,
        queue=queue,
        )

    do_this >> then_this
```

This above approach is working for one of our larger scale DAGs (Airflow 1.10.12) so please let me know if there are issues in implementing.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer on subdag deadlock issue fix. I am facing issue with subdag operator where in multiple tasks are to be run in parallel but fails with Deadlock after running certain tasks. 

Wanted to know where in the configuration file we have to set the queue? I see you have defined specific queue for each operator. Also how queue helps in subdag. I have gone through certain documents but internal working of subdag and deadlock is not clear to me. Can you point me to any such good document.

Comment: I tried doing the same , but my subdag is not even triggering.